# Prove: a matrix is element of General Linear Group

Tags: linear-algebra

Given field $K$ and $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & A_{12}\\0 & B\end{bmatrix} \in K^{n,n} \\ \\$ where $B \in K^{n-1,n-1}$

Prove:
$A \in GL_n(K)$ if and only if $B \in GL_{n-1}(K)$

This is part of a problem set on Row echelon form, been on it for awhile and would like a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$ \begin{bmatrix}a&b^T\\c&D\end{bmatrix}\cdot  \begin{bmatrix}1&A_{1,2}\\0&B\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}a&aA_{1,2}+b^TB\\c&cA_{1,2}+DB\end{bmatrix}$$
So for $\begin{bmatrix}a&b^T\\c&D\end{bmatrix}$ to be the inverse of $A$, it is necessary that $a=1$ and $c=0$ and $DB=1$, in particular it is necessary that $B$ is inveritble (with inverse $D$.
On the other hand, if $B$ is invertible and we let $D=B^{-1}$, $a=1$, $c=0$, $b=(-A_{1,2}D)^T$, we have exhibited an inverse of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

$det(A) \neq 0 \iff det(B) \neq  0$ because $det(A) = det(B)$. Compute determinant of $A$ along its first column.

Non zero determinant implies invertible matrix.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what methods you have at hand to find out whether a matrix is invertible.

One way would be to use determinants. Since the determinant is a multilinear form, you can by subtracting the first column sufficiently many times from the other columns, show that
$$
\det (A) = \det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & B \end{pmatrix} = 1 \cdot \det (B)
$$
and get the statement.

Another would be to find a matrix $C$ such that $CA = I_{n}$, the identity matrix. You can relate this question in the same way, using elementary column transformations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#Row-addition_transformations), to the invertibility of $B$.

Yet another way would be to show that $A$ has full rank, which can be achieved by the same methods.

So in the end, it boils down of using elementary transformations to get rid of the $A_{12}$ which reduces the problem to the analogous problem for $B$.

Hope that helps!

Andre